# Extracting JSON response from JSON Object in PHP

Tags: php, json

I search whole stackoverflow for my solution but didn't get exact answer to problem I am facing.

I have following JSON

[image: Inital JSON]

I want it to convert to the following output:

[image: Final JSON]

IN SHORT: omit Total Count line.

I want resulting JSON in BIG Bracket [.,.,.] omitting total_count: 3

What i did

```
$output = json_decode($json);
echo $output->entries;
```

What I see in my screen

```
Array
```

Comment: Try `print_r(json_encode($output->entries));`

Comment: BTW - we don't want pictures of stuff, we need the actual stuff posted here. We cannot work with pictures.

Comment: This has nothing to do with extracting from JSON. You simply can't use `echo` to print an array. Use `print_r` or `var_dump`.

Comment: @JayBlanchard  Thank You so much . Your code work perfectly. This is what i want. God Bless You